# Size Image widget to parent height but overflow width

Tags: flutter

I would like to create an Image widget that sizes to the height of it's parent, but then overflows the width of the parent based on the aspect ratio of the displayed image. I've tried `FittedBox` and a combination of `LayoutBuilder` and `SizedOverflowBox`, but no luck. So far I've only been able to get the image to size to the parent in both width and height.

Is there a combination of widgets that will give me this behavior?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I ended finding a very straight forward way to do this using the OverflowBox widget:

```
new Container(
  child: new OverflowBox(
    minWidth: 0.0, 
    minHeight: 0.0, 
    maxWidth: double.infinity, 
    child: new Image(
      image: new AssetImage('assets/images/bubbles.jpg'), 
      fit: BoxFit.cover)) 
),
```

When provided double.INFINITY for the maxWidth and no value for maxHeight the OverflowBox sized the image to the height of the container and the width required to display the full image based on the given height.

Comment: @Gunter: I want to use InteractiveViewer on an image but how can we restrict to InteractiveViewer's max width and max height to parent width/height. InteractiveViewer zoom should not be larger than outer container widget's width and height. How can we achieve this task. Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Give this a try:

```
new Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    image: new DecorationImage(
      image: new AssetImage(
        'assets/images/custom_birthday_card.jpg',
      ),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
);
```

If you still have a problem after this, check out my card example on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sabdar18/Flutter-Birthday-Card/blob/master/lib/main.dart).

Comment: From what I can tell this approach is doing the same as the other things I've tried. It sizes the image (DecorationImage in this case) to the size of the container and centers the painted image and fills it vertically while clipping it horizontally. I'm trying to get the image to be sized larger horizontally than the parent container, so that it is not clipped and can render the full image.

Comment: I was able to get my scenario working using OverflowBox

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with what i tried to achieve :)

Comment: this doesn't support loader!