# Flutter : how to crop decorationImage

Tags: flutter

In flutter, I load an image that is larger than the screen. My thoughts were that I would load the image, and crop it (clip it) without any resizing.

When I run, flutter gives me the following message:

```
════════ Exception caught by painting library ══════════════════════════════════
Image assets/images/3.0x/pic.jpg has a display size of 1124×2436 but a decode size of 2700×1965, which uses an additional 13360KB.

Consider resizing the asset ahead of time, supplying a cacheWidth parameter of 1124, a cacheHeight parameter of 2436, or using a ResizeImage.
```

The image is in my asset folder.
I do not want to use `ResizeImage`, as this scales the image. I want to do a very simple cropping.

I have tried to use ClipRect, or SizedBox, but all this seem to happen too late, and the message above continues to appear. This message does not appear when I use `ResizeImage`.

```
       Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        // image: ResizeImage(
                        //   AssetImage('assets/pic.jpg'),
                        //   width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio).ceil(),
                        //   height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio).ceil(),
                        // )
                        image: AssetImage('assets/pic.jpg')),
                  ),
                ),
```

Is there something similar to `ResizeImage`, but that I can use from cropping?

Or any other method that's more appropriate?

Comment: Try adding " fit: BoxFit.cover,"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583031/size-image-widget-to-parent-height-but-overflow-width

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it does not solve the problem. The image appears correctly, but I still get the same error message, as the image is still loaded in its full size.

Comment: Please share a reproducible code file, to regenerate this issue on my system. Thank you